# Java several conditions with the help of for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I wonder if it is possible to have minimal code for this:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++){    
      /*I want to replace this condition with (x%number == 0) 
        instead of writing out condition for every number, but 
        it did not work with for (int number = 1; number <= 3; number++)
        in (x%number == 0), as it prints out every x and number 
      */
    if ((x%1) == 0 && (x%2) == 0 & (x%3) == 0){
       System.out.println(success!);
    }    
}
```

Comment: have a look at my answer, if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think
`x % a == 0 && x % b == 0 && x % c == 0`
is equalent to
<strike>x % (a * b * c) == 0</strike>

**UPDATE**
Multiplication is incorrect, you need to use [LCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple): `x % lcm(a, b, c)`

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, I need to use GCD of these numbers :\

Comment: @Pshemo Yep. I'm ashamed of me :(

Comment: No need, at least +2 people didn't see that either :)

Comment: Nikita, thanks for the answer. However, I have at least twenty different divisors. Is there another way to write than lcm (a, b, c)? Maybe store them in an array?

Comment: @wagashi take Harmeet's or Steve's solution and replace inner loop so it iterates throug numbers in array.

Comment: This is elegant, but now the problem is writing a lcm function!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look :

```
for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++){
  boolean flag = false;
    for(int num = 1; num <= 3; num++){
       if ((x%num) == 0 ){
          flag = true;
       }else{
          flag = false;
          break;
       }
    }
    if(flag){
            System.out.println(x + " success!");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
6 success!
```

I know the code is looking a little horrified but will work for any value of `x` and `num`

Comment: I think OP means it's successful only if they're *all* zero.

Comment: Now, think of this: the condition stays true until a single condition fails.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you'd need to make a comp sci professor happy:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++){    
    boolean success = true;
    for (int number = 1; number <= 3; number++) {
        if ((x % number) != 0) {
            success = false;
        }
    }
    if (success) {
       System.out.println("success!");
    }    
}
```

although note: (x % 1) is always 0.

This is what you'd need to make me happy, according to my rule of "avoid nested loops":

```
for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
    if (testNumber(x)) 
        System.out.println(x + " success!");
    }
}

private static boolean testNumber(int x) {
    for (int number = 1; number <= 3; number++) {
        if ((x % number) != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```